# What better way to index the array of data in Lucene?

Tags: java, apache, lucene

dear programmers! 
I have a question for the people who worked with ***Apache Lucene***.
 
What better way to index the array of data in ***Lucene***? 
I use

```
arr [i] = Field: "arr." + i + ".data"
```

Java Code:

```
Field field = new StringField(
                "arr." + i + ".data",
                arr[i], Field.Store.YES);
doc.add(field);
```

Comment: It depends entirely on how you want to search for it :) Please tell us how you want to use it in search.

Comment: I use, in addition, arr.size ... 
But I do not know how to look for it, so I'm asking ...

Comment: Why you are saving `arr.` and `.data` in the first place?

Comment: Can i save different values in fields with the one name in the single document?

Comment: Have a look at MultiValued fields.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is the recommend way to do it. You can then search across all the values.

```
for (int i=0; i<arr.length; i++ {
    Field field = new StringField("field_name", arr[i], Field.Store.YES);
    doc.add(field);
}
```

Comment: If I want to get the result from a query, for example, I want to retrieve the whole value of field_name, all the data in arr, What should I do? Now, the filed is setted with Field.Store.YES, I can only get the first element in arr, I can't get all the elements in arr.